# Summarize distribution of factors in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, summarization

Say I have a data.frame like this:

```
  X1   X2   X3
1 A    B    A
2 A    C    B
3 B    A    B
4 A    A    C
```

I would like to count the occurrences of A, B, C, etc. in each column, and return the result as

```
    A_count B_count C_count
X1  3       1       0       
X2  2       1       1
X3  1       2       1
```

I'm sure this question has a thousand duplicates, but I can't seem to find an answer that works for me :(

By running

```
apply(mydata, 2, table)
```

I get something like

```
$X1
   B     A
   1     3
$X2
   A     C     B
   2     1     1
```

But it's not exactly what I want and if I try to build it back into a data frame, it doesn't work because I don't get the same number of columns for every row (like $X1 above where there are no C's).

What am I missing?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor to include the factor levels common to each column, then tabulate. I would also recommend using `lapply()` instead of `apply()`, as `apply()` is for matrices.

```
df <- read.table(text = "X1   X2   X3
1 A    B    A
2 A    C    B
3 B    A    B
4 A    A    C", h=T)

do.call(
    rbind, 
    lapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=levels(unlist(df)))))
)
#    A B C
# X1 3 1 0
# X2 2 1 1
# X3 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your data frame is `x`, I would simply do:

```
do.call(rbind, tapply(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE),
                      rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x)),
                      table))

#  A B C
#1 3 1 0
#2 2 1 1
#3 1 2 1
```

---

**Benchmarking**

```
# a function to generate toy data
# `k` factor levels
# `n` row
# `p` columns
datsim <- function(n, p, k) {
  as.data.frame(replicate(p, sample(LETTERS[1:k], n, TRUE), simplify = FALSE),
                col.names = paste0("X",1:p), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  }

# try `n = 100`, `p = 500` and `k = 3`
x <- datsim(100, 500, 3)

## DirtySockSniffer's answer
system.time(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(u) table(factor(u, levels=levels(unlist(x)))))))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 21.240   0.068  21.365 

## my answer
system.time(do.call(rbind, tapply(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE), rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x)), table)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.108   0.000   0.111
```

Dirty's answer can be improved, by:

```
## improved DirtySockSniffer's answer
system.time({clevels <- levels(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE));
             do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(u) table(factor(u, levels=clevels))))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.108   0.000   0.108
```

---

**Also consider user20650's answer**:

```
## Let's try a large `n`, `p`, `k`
x <- datsim(200, 5000, 5)

system.time(t(table(stack(lapply(x, as.character)))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.592   0.052   0.646
```

While my answer does:

```
system.time(do.call(rbind, tapply(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE), rep(1:ncol(x), each = nrow(x)), table)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.844   0.056   1.904
```

Improved Dirty's answer does:

```
system.time({clevels <- levels(unlist(x, use.names = FALSE));
             do.call(rbind, lapply(x, function(u) table(factor(u, levels=clevels))))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.240   0.012   1.263
```

Comment: Hi Zheyuan, not important but on my laptop `levels(u)[u]` is a bit slower than `as.character`. (which i would think makes sense as im sure the r folks have this optimised)

Comment: for the second example, it looks as if it is faster as as.numeric is called on a smaller vector, rather than the full vector. So if needing to convert to numeric, it looks as if it would be faster, as you say.